# How to determine if this sequence converges? (Complex sequence)

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

In $(\mathbb C,{\Vert .\Vert)}$, I have a sequence $$x_n=\left(\frac{2n^3+n}{n^3}+\frac{3in}{n+1}\right).$$

Learning from my previous question, I found the limit of $x_n$ to be $x=(2+3i)$. But how would this sequence converges?

I worked from $$x_n=\left|\left(\frac{2n^3+n}{n^3}+\frac{3in}{n+1}\right)-(2+3i)\right|$$

$$x_n=\left|\frac{n+n^2+3in^3}{n^4+n^3}\right| < \left|\frac{n+n^2+3in^3}{n^3}\right|$$

But how would I continue from there?

Comment: What happens to the substraction?

Comment: Hi @abatkai, I combined it with the 2 terms. As in, I simplified all 3 terms into 1 common denominator. Is that okay to do that or?

Comment: Yes. OK. Then it is better not to delete the $n^4$ term, but the $n^3$ term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make life simpler if you avail yourself of the fact that a sequence of complex numbers converges to $z$ iff its real part converges to $\Re(z)$ and its imaginary part converges to $\Im(z)$.

This simplifies the algebra.  For the real part, you have
$$\left|{2n^3 + n\over n^3} - 2\right| = {1\over n^2} \rightarrow 0\;
{\rm as}\; n\to\infty. $$

For the imaginary part, you have
$$\left|{3n\over n+1} - 3\right| = {3\over n+1} \to 0 \;{\rm as}\; n\to\infty. $$